# Jquery animate with function won't queue: false

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, queue

I'm having trouble with the following code:

```
$(".active").animate({
            opacity:0
        },{queue: false, duration:1000}, function(){  
            console.log("queue??");
            $(".active").css('display', 'none');
            $(".active").removeClass("active");
            initiatePage();
        });
```

After adding `queue: false`, the `function()` ain't running at all... but if I don't, they just queue up, and I don't want that to happen either.. Is there a way to make this animation and everything going with it `queue: false`??

Let me know if I can provide anything to make it easier for you to help..

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Read the [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) manual. When using the `options` the callback should be passed using the `complete` option.

> complete: A function to call once the animation is complete.

```
$(".active").animate({opacity:0},{
    queue       : false,
    duration    : 1000,
    complete    : function() {  
        $(this).hide().removeClass('active');
        initiatePage();
    }});
```

Comment: in this case, you can also cache the $('.active') into a variable

Comment: Thanks. Actually it's better to use `this` in case one or more of the elements going through the animation at the same time.

Comment: it's hard to tell from the OP's code if he wants everything to animate or just the current one

Comment: the `complete` callback will run once for every element in the jquery stack - separately. That way an element's animation callback will only affect itself.

Answer (score 0):

With the core plugin [jquery-timing](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/) you can shorten the solution:

```
$(".active").animate({opacity:0},{queue:'foo', duration:1000})
    .join('foo').hide().removeClass('active').then(initiatePage);
```

Using [.join()](http://creativecouple.github.com/jquery-timing/api/animate/.join.html) in the jQuery chain does the trick.